# Can I use c++ to traverse DOM from C# BHO?

Tags: c#, c++, internet-explorer, dllimport, bho

I'm writing a Browser Helper Object (BHO) for Internet Explorer in C#!

I want to look for text nodes in the DOM, which requires me to traverse the whole DOM tree if I want to differentiate between text nodes and other types of nodes. This is supposedly time consuming in C#, but should be almost instantanious in C++ (?).

Is there a way to do the traversing in c++ instead? A dll that I can call from C# perhaps, using DllImport? Is it easy to pass the HTMLDocument to my externally exposed c++-method?

Any other ideas?

Cheers!

Comment: Just write the whole BHO in C++?

Comment: I have so much other logic already written in C#..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where did you get the "supposedly" from?  Most of the time will be spent in the code that implements the DOM.  Which was written in C++ by Microsoft.

Marshal.GetIUnknownForObject() gets you a raw interface pointer that you can pass to native code.  It needs to QI that pointer for IHtmlDocument2 and take it from there.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/12/18/1317290.aspx and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/08/21/agcore-addon-hangs-internet-explorer.aspx are my sources on why not to write a BHO in managed code. I expect this is true for egrunin as well.

Comment: The CLR version injection problem has nothing to do with perf.  Solved in .NET 4.0 btw.

Answer (score 0):

> This is supposedly time consuming in C#,

**This is just wrong.**

Most of the user's time will be spent waiting for the HTML to arrive at the browser, and for the browser to draw it on the screen. Compared to that, walking the DOM (in any language) is a snap.

Comment: Walking the DOM can be quite slow, due to marshalling. That's one reason why the Skype toolbar hurts performance so much, for instance. But the point that C# is much slower than C++ isn't really correct.

Comment: We're both right. I've written lots of code that walks the DOM, mostly but not all in BHOs, using C++, VB, and C#. Yes, it takes time, and yes, C++ isn't noticeably faster than the others, no doubt for the reason you cite.